# Unable to change data type to pass through stats CDF function

Tags: python, pandas, types, statistics, cdf

I have a data frame with 4 columns: sample_means, sample_size, MW_wind_speed, and sample_stdev.  From these values I have calculated a test statistics ("test_stat") which I would like to pass through the stats package CDF function (see last line of code) to calculate a p-value for each row in the dataframe. However, I keep getting an error for the last line saying:

"TYPE ERROR: int object is not subscriptable"

I cannot change the type of my test_stat data because it is a series, so I am not sure what to do.  How do I need to adjust my data to pass i through the CDF function?

```
#define data from columns of the dataframe
sample_means = new_df['sample_mean']
sample_size = new_df['sample_size']
MW_wind_speed = new_df['MW_wind_speed']
sample_stdev = new_df['sample_stdev']

#calculate s value and z_value
s_x = sample_stdev/(np.sqrt(sample_size-1))
test_stat = (np.abs(sample_means - MW_wind_speed))/s_x

#calculate p-values by passing z value through CDF function
from scipy.stats import norm
p_values = 2[1-norm.cdf(test_stat)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a good way to get around it!  I think the problem with the type was that I was not including 2*(1-norm.cdf(test_stat))

```
#calculate s value and z_value
s_x = sample_stdev/(np.sqrt(sample_size-1))
z_value = (np.abs(sample_means - MW_wind_speed))/s_x

new_df['s_value'] = s_x
new_df['test_statistic'] = test_stat

new_df = new_df.dropna()

#make a a t distribution object for t with 10 deg of freedom (best approximation)
t_dist = stats.t(10)
cdf_values = t_dist.cdf(test_stat)
p_values = 2*(1-cdf_values)
```